# Data structure loop for all datasets

Tags: r

this is my very first question.

I want to have an overview of the data structure of all datasets in global environment, as the funcion *srt* would do for just one dataset.

My guess is:

```
for (dataset in ls()) {
  str(dataset)
}
```

But this only return the dataset names.

Comment: Probably `ls.str(mode = "list")` will be enough as `data.frame`s are lists. You could also search for specific names using the `pattern` argument

Comment: @DavidArenburg: I would delete my answer as yours is better, but I dont understand the restriction on list/data.frame. He asked for all datasets. Is that a synonym for data.frame i was not aware of?

Comment: @BigDataScientist I don't know what he meant by *datasets*. I just made a guess.

Comment: sorry for missspelling. I guess I meant data frame to all things in the global environment of rstudio
@DavidArenburg 's answer does identify each of the files but does not show lists that are inside lists (BigSataScientist 's does)

Answer (score 1):

Almost ;)

```
for (dataset in ls()) {
  print(dataset)
  str(get(dataset))
}
```

Explanation:
`ls()` returns an array of strings with the names. So if you use `str()` for a string, you get the name. To "get" the variable corresponding to the name use,...`get()` :)

Comment: Super! How can I display the name of each dataset before the command execution? Your proposal does work but returns all response in a sequence without specifying which dataset it is

Comment: You could get that by combining it with your code, no? :) What do you think about David`s Answer, it would be shorter. I made an edit for the names.